# rails NoMethodError: undefined method " " for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, nomethoderror

I am working on rails tutorial by Michael Hartl's ([chapter 9](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users/)).

I get this error:

```
 Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_remembering:
NoMethodError: undefined method `FILL_IN' for nil:NilClass
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

FILL-IN was added in [chapter 8](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#code-improved_remember_me_test/) and there wasn't any problem till chapter 9.
I tried a lot but I can't fix it. Here is my UsersLoginTest class.

```
class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
       get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Simulate a user clicking logout in a second window.
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end

  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_equal assigns(:user).FILL_IN, FILL_IN
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end
end
```

Line 42 is:

```
assert_equal assigns(:user).FILL_IN,FILL_IN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILL_IN` in this case is a placeholder.  Michael expects you to replace this with the correct text.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use an @user instance variable in listing 9.29 if you did the "login with remembering exercise" in listing 8.62. It took me a while to realize this, so it might help other beginners to see what Shadwell's suggestions look like in the code:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in @user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      redirect_back_or @user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Flash.now designed for rendered pages, disappears at the next request.
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

**users_login_test.rb**

```
# ...

 test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_equal assigns(:user).remember_token, cookies['remember_token']
  end

# ...
```

To be fair, Michael Hartl advises us to solve the exercises in separate topic branches with git.

Answer (score 3):

The errors shows that `assigns(:user)` is returning nil.

`assigns` tests for an instance variable set in your controller. The expectation here is that you have a value set for `@user` in your controller and that when the method `FILL_IN` is called on it that it will equal `FILL_IN`. Once you've fixed the problem of `@user` being `nil` you'll need to actually fill in those placeholders.